# firefox getUserMedia error on Dell / Windows 7

Tags: windows, firefox, webrtc, quickblox

I get firefox errors on a windows when quickblox tries to get the media, despite the fact I click "share selected device" etc

ERROR MSG:
SourceUnavailableError: Failed to allocate videosource

CODE:

```
        QB.webrtc.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function(err, stream) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            QB.webrtc.reject(callee.id);
          } else {
            QB.webrtc.accept(callee.id);
          }
        });
```

Is there a known issue here?
I'm running a Dell 3550 on Windows 7 64 bit and the version of firefox is 38.0.5
The same code works great on Chrome, and on a Mac works on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I am guessing that, it is because, a camera is already being used in chrome browser already( or some other program probably),  try closing other browsers and try again.

Comment: Have you tried changing your media parameters? It may be an issue with Firefox trying to grab the feed with those specific parameters(framesize and rate). Is this just a built in camera? Or an external camera? Have you tried a different camera on your Dell for Firefox?

Comment: The device is being used by some other process. After giving the sharing permissions, the unavailability of the stream raises this error. Like mido22 suggested, close all processes using the device and then try again.